# Shiny random default

Tags: r, shiny

I'm interested in having a default selection for a shiny app that changes each time you refresh the page. So for example, in the hello world Shiny demo, instead of having the default selection be `500`, I would like it to be `sample(1:1000,1)`

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/example-01-hello.html

I've tried putting a randomly generated value directly in the `value =` part, but that seems to only be updated each time the app is started, not each time the page is loaded.

How can I go about having a random default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `updateSliderInput`, e.g

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins", value = sample(1:500,1))
  })

 ....
}
```

Don't forget to add *session* variable to the *server* function definition and update *max* value in *sliderInput* to 500.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a reactive UI element.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
uiOutput("slider")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a plot of the distribution. The expression
  # is wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically 
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot 
  #

  output$slider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1, 
                max = 1000, 
                value =runif(1,1,1000))

  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$obs)
    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
    dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
    hist(dist)
  })
}

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This will randomly select a new value in the slider. Is this what you were after?